# Is there a way to tell a citizen where to live?

Tags: tropico-4

One occasionally irritating problem in Tropico 4 (and 3, looking back on it) is that there seems to be no way to control who goes to live in which home; more often than not it's first-come-first serve -- and no matter that the apartment building I just put up right next to the garage by the fisheries is a much nicer place to live, three of the fishermen will stay in the tenement five miles down the road near the city center.

Is there any way to change that short of forcible evictions (causes unhappiness) or dynamiting the tenements?

**EDIT** Bit late, but came up with a workable method that causes a lot less unhappiness than evictions: Drastically increase the rent in the building you want cleared. Even the people who can afford it will likely abandon it for someplace nicer if they can, and when it's empty, it can be safely dynamited and replaced with a better residential building.

Comment: Do note that people can't live in a building that costs more per month than one-third of their monthly wage.

Comment: What @Ullallulloo said. It took me a little while to realize why I had people in shacks even though I had open space in my housing (unemployment).

Comment: Issue the free housing verdict and make sure there is enough space.

Comment: @Assylum And lose out on all that delicious income from office buildings making cash per citizen paying rent in the area? Shirley, you jest.

Comment: @shadur Idk, I always earn enough even with this edict issued.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you may be a dictator, but some decisions still belong to the citizens.  In the real world, there are plenty of things that influence where someone lives other than convenience.  Given time and a nice enough alternative, they may eventually move, but not without some resulting stress (unhappiness).

Comment: It turns out that if you want them to voluntarily move sooner you can just raise the rent on the building they're currently in to well beyond their ability to afford.

Answer (score 3):

> ..no matter that the apartment building I just put up right next to the garage by the fisheries is a much nicer place to live, three of the fishermen will stay in the tenement five miles down the road near the city center.

Are you sure they can afford it? IIRC, people in Tropico will pay up to 1/3 of their *household* salary for rent, which means that if they're getting paid $5, they'll pay only $1 for the house, unless they're married to someone who works.

Very often, they'll pick a high quality place near their workplaces, and will often move houses if there's a better home.

Comment: By the time I start plunking down apartments/modern apartment blocks like mushrooms, minimum uneducated wages are well into double digits.

Comment: The rent hasn't been scaled beyond their means? The AI should pick out desirable locations first, even if it's expensive (as long as it's within their budget). It could be things like crime/pollution in that area or it could be influenced by a spouse's workplace. Or simply needing some time before they choose to move to a better location.

Comment: I've cranked the rent down to T$1, but that usually causes homeless vagrants to pounce on the damn place before the workers I wanted to get in there did.

Answer (score 0):

After thinking it over some more and trying a few additional tricks I figured out how to do it with at least a *lesser* happiness penalty than a straight eviction -- By building the new building, then set the rent for the old building to something stupidly high, all inhabitants were motivated to move to new, better and *cheaper* apartment space almost immediately.